# Animating Picture Transitions

Tags: android, animation, user-interface, imageview

I'm starting out with Android development, and I'm kind of stuck. Basically, I have a layout with dynamically added ImageViews, and I want to have the ImageViews change their image every once in a while. However, I'd like to add some sort of transition or changing animation, like a flip or a flash.

I don't really know where to even start to look for an answer to this question. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The android framework has this totally covered:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html

Basically, you are looking to define "tween" animations between your drawables (imageviews). After you define your animations you can even define a set of drawables to show one after the other using frame-animation.

Check out the following for all the gory details:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html